# Schema moongo: Valor por defecto para array y objeto dentro de objeto

Tags: javascript, nodejs, moongose

tengo el siguiente código

```
var moongose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = moongose.Schema;

var peliculaSchema = Schema(
{
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    content: {type: String, required: true},
    date: {type: String, required: [true,'La fecha es obligatoria']},
    category: {type: [String] , enum: {values:['accion', 'aventura', 'romance', 'terror'],message: 'La pelicula no puede ser de ese tipo.'}},
    director: 
    {
        nombre: {type: String, default:'Director desconocido'},
        apellidos: {type: String, default: null},
    },
    image: {type:String, default: null}
});

module.exports = moongose.model('Pelicula',peliculaSchema);
```

Mi problema es que las propiedades *director* y *category* no se guardan en la base de datos, ya que el *default* no funciona, hay alguna manera de poner el *default* a esas propiedades?

Esto es lo que se guarda en la BD

```
    "pelicula": {
        "image": null,
        "_id": "6021e3b6565a1f320408c174",
        "title": "gladiator",
        "content": "es una plelicula sobre",
        "date": "20/20/20",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Se que el problema es que la *category* es un array de strings y que los parametros de *director* son un objeto dentro de otro, pero me pregunto si hay alguna forma de que el *default* funcione en estos casos.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez esto te funcione:

```javascript
var peliculaSchema = Schema(
{
    category: {
       type: [String], 
       enum: {
         values:['accion', 'aventura', 'romance', 'terror'],
         message: 'La pelicula no puede ser de ese tipo.'
       },
      default: null
    },
    director: 
    {
       nombre: {type: String, default:'Director desconocido'},
       apellidos: {type: String, default: null},
       default: {
         nombre: 'Director desconocido'
         apellidos: null
       }
    },

});
```